# AnyLogic model : Can I use the string entry from the Database file as a condition in selectoutput5?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model that sorts the agents based on the department column. I tried the timestamp column from the database for the agent arrival and it works fine. now along the process, at one point the agents have to be moved based on the department column on the same database. but when I select it as shown in the picture, I get an error of "Not Unique value". I have no idea how to rectify. please help!!

[This is the properties of SelectOutput5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4692.png)

[This is the error i receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NswcH.png)

I want to use the string entries of the database column as the condition for the selectoutput5 block. I want to know if it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to ensure that the SQL statement returns a unique result (i.e. just one).

However, I would never do this, tbh. Querying the dbase during model runtime is bad practice.

It is much better to store any data you need about your agents into the agents themselves as parameters.

Then, in your `SelectOutput`, you can simply ask the agent via `agent.myParamValue == true` or whatever.

The AnyLogic tutorials that apply the dbase show you the best practice

Comment: The database included into the model is acting as the source for the agents arrival, their department and details. The agent arrival is done correctly. Now I want to use the agent department column to move them into separate places. i want to know if it is possible.

Comment: its possible, but I'd advise against pulling any dbase data at runtime. Your errors suggest that you are querying data such that more than one result. Change the data or query to have 1 result and it should work